# How to add tooltip in jQuery Date Picker for disabled dates?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, tooltip, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working on a web form and needs to limit date selection to a particular range, rest of dates needs to be disabled. I have implemented datepicker using jquery-ui.

**Requirements**:

1. Needs to show tooltip on disabled dates
2. Different tooltip is needed for both, past and future dates

**Problem**:

I found solution to display tooltip and currently the tooltip is displayed only if date is allowed. I mean, if `beforeShowDay` returns `true` (allows date selection) then it shows tooltip otherwise it doesn't show for some reasons. But I only need it for disabled dates.

**Sample Code**:

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+5D',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var sDate = new Date("2020-10-16").toDateString();
        var newDate = date.toDateString();
        
        if(sDate == newDate){
            // problem lies here
            return [false, '', 'sdate equals'];
            
            // this does work but it allows date selection, which I don't need
            // return [true, '', 'sdate equals'];
        }else{
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

**Question**:

1. How can display tooltip for disabled dates only?
2. How can I create different tooltip for past and future dates?

Comment: You said " currently the tooltip is displayed only if date is allowed" which is not working as per thes snippet. Are you using jQuery tooltip ?

Comment: The problem is that `disabled` is used to disable the date, which means, that no DOM events are triggered to show the tooltip. This appears to be [a known limitation that jQuery recognizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26134445/7644018). If you inspect the calendar element DOM with the browser's tool, you will see that the element title _is_ set to the `sdate equals` value, but it will not be rendered to display.

Comment: @melvin yes, I am using default jQuery tooltip.

Comment: @PaulT. hmmm, is there any work around?

Comment: returning false from beforeShowDay and setting the tooltip works in version 1.9.2 of the jquery ui css, but doesn't in version 1.12.1, the difference is the newer version adds `pointer-events: none;` to the `.ui-state-disabled` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the results by adding `ui-datepicker-unselectable` class, it will disable date selection but won't disable entire element in DOM so tooltip can be displayed. You can get disabled element look and feel by adding few lines of css.

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    
        // assuming you want to start from today
        var startDate = new Date();
        
        // assuming end date 5 days in the future
        var endDate = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 5);
        
        if(date < startDate){
            return [true, 'ui-datepicker-unselectable', 'past date'];
        }else if(date > endDate){
            return [true, 'ui-datepicker-unselectable', 'future date'];
        }else{
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    },
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-unselectable a{
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

**PS:** The answer of your both questions is available in above code snippet.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the work-around example. I've not had a chance to look into a work-around, as I've never used tooltips with the calendar.

Comment: @Atlas_Gondal thank you so much for the solution, it's very clean and worked the way needed!

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery UI uses CSS on its disabled elements to turn off the pointer events needed to display a tooltip. All you need to do to show a tooltip on a disabled date is add this CSS to override the jQuery UI.

```
html .ui-datepicker .ui-state-disabled {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```